# Creating Interactive Charts

Tags: 8, charts

I'd like to create a page in D8 that allows my users to input some values. Once they've done that I'd like them to click a button that then creates two pie charts for them based on the values they input.

I see the [Charts Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) is not available for D8. Wondering if anyone here has suggestions for how best to accomplish this in D8 as of this writing?

Comment: Hey Sage, merci for the (late) accept of my answer. Any feedback about your experience with Easychart in D8?

Comment: Np. Actually I don't have any feedback other than it seems to work great. My developer did all the work with it so I don't have much to comment on other than it's got some nice features.

Comment: Well, that **does** seem like interesting feedback. I read what you wrote like "it's a kind of black box to me, but all I know is that it seems to work great" ... So thank you for your comment here anyway ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Easychart](https://www.drupal.org/project/easychart) module, which has an official release for Drupal 8 (also for Drupal 7).

It is a graphical user interface, using the [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts) javascript library as its charting engine (which may require a commercial license though). It claims to support every Highcharts chart-type and option.

Some more details about this module:

- It defines a new content type (= *Chart*) used to add charts to your site.
- It creates a chart widget that can be used in your own content types.
- It integrates with the [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module and provides an editor button to add charts to your WYSIWYG content (*CKeditor* and *TinyMCE* are supported).
- It provides an intuitive interface to configure charts through the Easychart plugin.
- It supports pasting of CSV data to create charts from it.
- [overheid.vlaanderen.be](http://overheid.vlaanderen.be/bedrijfsinformatie/toegankelijke-websites) contains some real world examples of a Drupal website (not yet D8 though) with some charts created with Easycharts (ignore the text on that page if you're not familiar with this language, just concentrate on the charts).

## Resources:

- [Module documentation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/easychart/tree/README.txt?h=8.x-3.x).
- [Video demonstration](https://vimeo.com/137681122).

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable in code, you may like to directly use the [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/).

Example pie chart:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```